# 2 Public IP's - 2 exchange servers - Need port forwarding to both

Tags: exchange, cisco, port-forwarding

I am currently setting up 2 new servers at a Church/Private school. They are migrating from one single exchange server to two separate servers, they are set up through vlan with different subnets. I have a Cisco ASA 5505 and 2 public IP's. Is it even possible to run both exchange servers for each separate domain? Can I port forward different public IP's on the same port, then to both servers respectively? Or will I need to get a separate ASA ? They are SBS2011 servers and both are running exchange 2010. I know this is a very difficult set up but I need to move forward and I am running into a wall trying to figure out the best option here. Any guidance in the right direction will be helpful. Both of the domains are completely separate from each other.

Ryanj

Comment: Of course you can. You have two public ip addresses. You have two Exchange servers. Create the appropriate NAT/port forwarding rule on the ASA to NAT/port forward the desired traffic (SMTP) from the appropriate public ip address to the corresponding internal ip address for each server.

Answer (score 0):

Incoming e-mail: Configure your external-facing DNS MX record to point to both external ip addresses and configure port forwarding so SMTP traffic to each external ip address goes to one of the internal Exchange Servers (i.e. external ip 1 goes to server 1, external ip 2 goes to server 2). Configure a receive connector on each Hub Transport to allow anonymous traffic. DNS round robin will roughly balance incoming traffic across both ip addresses and the Hub Transport servers will take care of routing the messages inside the organization.

Outgoing e-mail: Configure a send connector for domain "*" that uses both Hub Transport servers to route directly to the Internet. External e-mail will go out through the default gateway of each Hub Transport.

Note: This is assuming Exchange 2007 or later, one Exchange Organization, two Active Directory Sites, and that both Exchange servers have the Hub Transport role installed.